# syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2022 in cshtml files not working

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, syntax-highlighting

I am using Visual Studio 2022 on my working laptop and the syntax highlighting in .cshtml files does not work

[image: Syntax not highlighted]

which makes it hard to debug the code

HTML code usually is highlighted correctly

JS code is not higlighted at all

on my personal laptop same version of VS 17.7.7

**What I tried**

- Deleting all bin, obj & .vs folders
- Running .\devenv.exe /ResetUserData
- Running .\devenv.exe /UpdateConfiguration & .\devenv.exe /ClearCache
- Importing settings from my personal laptop
- Exporting my settings from working laptop to personal one does not break the highlighting there
- adding .cshtml files to be explicitely highlighted as JavaScript in the text editor settings

Has anyone experienced this ? I saw some posts about versions of VS 2015 and VS 2017
But unfortunately any of the fixes did not work for me

Comment: Are your braces off? I feel like the very last `}` is out of place, or another one is.  I think the `var formData` opening brace is missing its closing one? Double check them all.

Comment: @TimothyG. the braces are not off it can be see from the screenshot the last } is closing of the function.. still even if the braces or anything would be off the visualstudio should highlight the syntax thus not making all of the JS text white...
and the issue would be on my personal laptop the same when I pull the branch that is shown in the screenshot higlighting works fine on my personal laptop...
Issue is related to my working laptop only